# Accessing Every File on the File System (no matter what) On Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, file-permissions

In c#, on a windows 7 machine, how can I programmatically access every file on the file system as though I was a "Master Administrator".

The main priority here, is that after my c# program is installed, that it won't run into any file/folder access permission problems. My program runs as a windows service, and it must allow a user to backup any files on the file system.

Comment: I believe you have an overly simplistic concept of what "backup" is. It's not simply copying files. What's more, this doesn't take into account files thare are in-use, and possibly being changed while you are doing the backup, leaving them in a possibly corrupted state. You don't take into account Encrypted files, backup and restoring of EFS keys, multiple filesystems, file state, You also don't take into account system state, or how you restore it. There's a ton of things a backup program has to do, and I suggest you start learning what that is before you go off writing a lot of code.

Comment: Each thing you mentioned is valuable. My program works on Windows XP Pro, but I'm trying to make it work on Windows 7 and I keep running to permission problems that I *don't* encounter running under the "system" account of Windows XP Pro.

Answer (score 5):

I would have thought that it would work if you just make sure that the service runs under an account in the `Backup Operator` group. I thought that group had access to all files no matter what permissions there are.

Quote from MS Support page:

*SID: S-1-5-32-551
Name: Backup Operators
Description: A built-in group. By default, the group has no members. Backup Operators can back up and restore all files on a computer, regardless of the permissions that protect those files. Backup Operators also can log on to the computer and shut it down.*

Though that page is for earlier versions of Windows so I'm not 100% certain that it's not been changed.

Comment: I don't think just running with Backup Operator privileges allows you to open any file. I'm pretty sure you need to open the files with FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS set (and maybe some other flags, too) using the CreateFile API.

Comment: Neither my comment nor the copied quote mentions opening files... when I wrote access I meant access to backup & restore though maybe I should have spelt that out.

Answer (score 3):

There is the [**Win32 backup API**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362514(v=VS.85).aspx) which is most likely what you want, maybe in combination with the [**Volume Shadow Service**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384648(VS.85).aspx). And your application has to have the [SeBackupPrivilege privilege](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446619(VS.85).aspx). Note, though, that files encrypted with EFS can be read, but only in their encrypted form.

Links which may also be interesting for you:

http://mutable.net/blog/archive/2006/11/21/an-intelligent-backup-system-for-windows-part-3.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362520(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You will have to configure the service to run under an account with sufficient privileges.

AFAIK the standard 'Local System' already has rather high privileges. But no matter what, you won't be able to access files that are reserved to the System account, or files that are in use exclusively. Your program will always have to be able to handle Access related exceptions.